# Derivation of MLE weight vector under conditional variance

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Suppose we have a data set $\lbrace \mathbf{x}_i, y_i, \sigma_{\mathbf{x}_i}\rbrace_{i=1}^n$ and each $\mathbf{x}_i \in \Bbb{R}^d$

Suppose I want to solve the following for the following:

$$\hat{\mathbf{w}}=\max_{\mathbf{w}} \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg[-\frac{(y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\cdot\mathbf{w})^2}{2\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_i}^2}-\ln\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_i}\sqrt{2\pi}\bigg] $$

I want to solve this. I have made an attempt but I think, due to lack of knowledge, I am approaching it wrong. I would like pointers on how to do it better.

My question is ***is there a way I can rewrite the derivation I did in an easier matrix notation so that it will make it possible for me to solve with simple matrix operations?***

***Step 1: I took the gradient***

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{0} &= \nabla_{\mathbf{w}}\sum_{i=1}^n \bigg[-\frac{(y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\cdot\mathbf{w})^2}{2\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_i}^2}-\ln\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_i}\sqrt{2\pi}\bigg]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg\langle\frac{x_i^1 (y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\cdot\mathbf{w})}{\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_i}^2},...,\frac{x_i^d (y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\cdot\mathbf{w})}{\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_i}^2}\bigg \rangle
\end{align*}

***Step 2: I tried to simplify***

I realized I could write the previous expression as

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{0} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{(y_1-\mathbf{x}_1\cdot\mathbf{w})}{\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_1}^2}& 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \frac{(y_2-\mathbf{x}_2\cdot\mathbf{w})}{\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_2}^2} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \frac{(y_n-\mathbf{x}_n\cdot\mathbf{w})}{\sigma_{\mathbf{x}_n}^2}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1d}\\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2d}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \cdots & x_{nd}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\vdots\\
1
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \Sigma^{-1} 
\begin{bmatrix}
(y_1-\mathbf{x}_1\cdot\mathbf{w})& 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & (y_2-\mathbf{x}_2\cdot\mathbf{w}) & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & (y_n-\mathbf{x}_n\cdot\mathbf{w})\\
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X} \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\vdots\\
1
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}

I feel there should be an easy set of matrix operations to then obtain $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$, but because of how I've organized the derivation, I think I'm having difficulty simplifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y =\begin{bmatrix}
y_1/\sigma_{x_1}\\
y_2/\sigma_{x_2}\\
\vdots\\
y_n/\sigma_{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}\\
$, 
$X=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1/\sigma_{x_1}\\
x_2/\sigma_{x_2}\\
\vdots\\
x_n/\sigma_{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}\\ $

Then your question can be written as 
$$\hat{w}=\min_{w}\left((Y-Xw)'(Y-Xw)\right) =\min_{w}\left(Y'Y -2w'X'Y + w'X'Xw\right)$$
Let $L = Y'Y -2w'X'Y + w'X'Xw$, we have 
$$\frac{dL}{dw}=-2X'Y+X'Xw  $$ 
Let the derivative vector be 0, we get

$$\hat w = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$$

Comment: Why doesn't the conditional variance make OLS inapplicable? I thought one of the assumptions for OLS was that you had to have homoscedasticity? Are you effectively eliminating that issue by dividing by the variances?

Comment: Assume your conditional variance means $\sigma_i^2$. The property of OLS is BLUE (best linear unbiased estimate) when the assumptions are met. If homoscedasticity is not true ($\sigma_i^2 \ne \sigma_i'^2$), then OLS is not BLUE, although it is unbiased.  After transformation, the random vector Y has the property of homogeneity. It is WLS (weighted least square). I assume $\sigma_i^2$ is known constant.